# Animating points in a polygon with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to animate the points in a polygon with the following code:

```
var lineWeight = 2.5,
    startPoints = [25,18,54,24,35,38,42,51,12,34,23,52,25,18],
    endPoints = [15,38,54,24,35,38,42,51,12,34,23,52,25,18];

var logo = Snap('.logo');

var p1 = logo.polygon().attr({
    points: startPoints,
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: lineWeight,
    strokeLinejoin: 'round'
});

setTimeout(function () {
    p1.animate({
        points: endPoints
    }, 2000, mina.elastic);
}, 2000);
```

When the `setTimeout` fires the animation the polygon simply disappears, and I get several errors in the console during the animation that look like this:

[image]

It looks like the animation is updating the value of the `points` attribute incorrectly. Any idea why, and how I might fix it?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

It works when using Snap.svg v3.0 for some reason, but not v4.1:

```js
(function($){
  var lineWeight = 2.5,
    startPoints = [25,18,54,24,35,38,42,51,12,34,23,52],
    endPoints = [40,10,54,24,35,38,42,51,12,34,23,52];

  var logo = Snap('.logo');

  var p1 = logo.polygon().attr({
    points: startPoints,
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: lineWeight,
    strokeLinejoin: 'round'
  });

  setTimeout(function () {
    p1.animate({
       points: endPoints
    }, 1000, mina.elastic);
  }, 2000);
 })();
```

```css
.logo {
  background: green;
  height: 68px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 68px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg class="logo"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Snap.svg animation function can take an array of values, and it will animate through them step by step.  As a result, it *doesn't* automatically convert your `endPoints` array to a string, the way it does when you use the `.attr()` function to set the `points` attribute to your `startPoints` array.

So instead of animating to a single string of points, you are animating through a series of single-number values.  And a single number is not a valid polygon `points` attribute!

To make it work, you're going to have to explicitly convert the `endPoints` array to a string.  You can do that by calling the array's `toString()` method, like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    p1.animate({
        points: endPoints.toString()
    }, 2000, mina.elastic);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: This all makes total sense, but for some reason it isn't working. Oddly enough, when I downgrade to Snap.svg v3.0 it works, but I see no notes on breaking changes to the API.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange.  Maybe file an issue on [their github page](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues)?  It could have been an unintentional break.

Comment: @BrandonDurham Did you ever find out why it doesn't work in 0.4.0?

Comment: Ah, never mind. Looks like there's an issue and a fix ready, it's just not implemented yet. https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/373